# refreshing Windows 8 giving problems

Tags: windows-8

Recently when I refreshed my pc with Windows 8. After the refreshing was complete and it rebooted, my start screen had no items except 4-5 apps Andwhen I tried to access the C:/ drive it failed to open with error "you don't haveenough previlages". I changed its permissions from security tab then I could access c:/.... But I don't know how to get apps back on start screen

Comment: refresh removes all apps/desktop programs. go to the store and reinstall the apps.

Comment: I still have those apps in startup folder but are not shown in start screen